# Blob or URL to image file for form data upload

Tags: javascript, file-upload, fetch, multipartform-data, form-data

I'm trying to take an image blob or url, and upload it via formdata as an image file type.

Here is the object I am working with (this.selectedImage):

```
{
 blob: "blob:http://localhost:3000/3018fad1-ff11-410e-b724-35bdd582435c"
 blobObj: Blob
   size: 673107
   type: "image/png"
 createdAt: "Wed, 21 Sep 2022 04:39:07 GMT"
 id: "ID_HERE"
 index: 1
 thumb: "IMG_URL_HERE"
 url: "IMG_URL_HERE"
}
```

Here are the docs for the place I am uploading the image: https://clipdrop.co/apis/docs/super-resolution#examples

And the code I am using. I grabbed this straight out of Postman as I can successfully make the API call there, and could not get the code in the documentation to work, so I tried this.

```
const file = new File([this.selectedImage], "imagename.jpg");
  var myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.append("x-api-key", "API_KEY_HERE");

  var formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("image_file", file, "image.png");
  formdata.append("upscale", "4");

  var requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: formdata,
    redirect: 'follow'
  };

  fetch("https://apis.clipdrop.co/super-resolution/v1", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

No matter what I do, I can't get the API to return correctly and best I can tell, it is because I am not formatting/converting the blob to an image file type correctly. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What is `this.selectedImage`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear, this.selectedImage is the object at the top of the post.

Comment: You need to pass the blob instance in the first argument, like so :  `new File([blob], "imagename.jpg");` so `[this.selectedImage.blobObj]` in your case